# Convert m4a with cover to mp4

Tags: video, homebrew, youtube, mp4, m4a

I've a m4a file with cover attached using mp4art; however Youtube doesn't support m4a. Supported formats - https://support.google.com/youtube/troubleshooter/2888402?visit_id=637603848977966877-3323728279&hl=en-GB&rd=1

Thus I need to convert m4a with cover image to mp4.

Using brew's ffmpeg didnt help

```
$ brew install ffmpeg
$ ffmpeg -i input.m4a output.mp4
[mp4 @ 0x7fbb6100de00] Could not find tag for codec h264 in stream #0, codec not currently supported in container
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:1 -- 
[aac @ 0x7fbb60015c00] Qavg: nan
Conversion failed!
```

Comment: macOS comes with [afconvert](https://ss64.com/osx/afconvert.html) which should be suitable tool for solving your problem.

Answer (score -1):

`.m4a` is typically the extension of [MPEG-4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_14) audio-only files.

`.mp4` is typically the extension of MPEG-4 video + audio files.

Your source file has the .m4a extension, suggesting that it is *audio only*.

As noted in the [Supported YouTube file formats](https://support.google.com/youtube/troubleshooter/2888402?visit_id=637603848977966877-3323728279&hl=en-GB&rd=1) page:
`Audio files, like MP3, WAV or PCM files, can't be uploaded to YouTube. You can use video editing software to convert your audio file to a video.`

Comment: The question is a bit unclear, but it seems that the OP is looking for a way to convert m4a with cover image to mp4 (to solve the "se video editing software to convert your audio file to a video" part).